# WSO2ESB 4.5.1 axi2 property ssl.client.auth.cert.X509 is always NULL

Tags: wso2-esb

When using the NIO SSL listener (org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener), there's no `HttpServletContext` available anymore (obviously), so digging into the possible Axis2 properties that could address the client certificate I found:

```
ssl.client.auth.cert.X509
```

This property, no matter what, is always null (I'm able to access other properties, so my code to access seems fine). Looking into the `HttpCoreNIOSSLListener`, it seems like it is filled whenever the request is done via HTTPS, but is not working in my case.

Am I looking into the right property? Did anyone succeed in retrieving this property? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Reported issue has been tested on WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and it is working as expected.

Comment: could you please confirm if it works with API manager 2.1 version ? I get null always.

Comment: I am not sure about the APIM 2.1.0