# WSO2 API manager to use (blocking) http/https

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have some need to access client certificates before calling the endpoint, so how can I access client certificates ? It looks like I cannot access `HttpServletRequest` object if using `NIO` transport/connector.

So I tried changing WSO2 API manager to use blocking http/https by changing following files

> 1) **axis.xml** - uncomment the transport senders to receivers to use
>   normal http/https transport instead of `PTT`.
>
> 2) **catalina-server.xml** - change Connector protocol to default
>   (`HTTP 1.1`).
>
> 3) **apimanager.xml** - change all the references of `http.nio.port`
>   to `mgt.transport.https.port`

After this, the endpoints are redirecting to carbon homepage. The https port 9443 seems does not look for API endpoints.

Is there any other config to be added ? 
Please point some direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve mutual ssl?

Comment: yes between client and api backend server. But I see the link says only about "Mutual SSL between API Gateway and backend". but is it supposed to be between client and API Gateway ?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you're trying to achieve Mutual SSL, it's supported by APIM OOTB.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Mutual+SSL+Support+for+API+Gateway

2) If you want to read the client certificate for some other reason, you can do it like this.

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();

// try to retrieve the certificate
Object sslCertObject = axis2MessageContext.getProperty("ssl.client.auth.cert.X509");

if(sslCertObject != null) {
    // if the certificate is available in the MessageContext,  it means that mutual SSL validation has been done
    // and succeed in the transport level.
    // So, you can return tru here

    //return true;

    // Following are some additional steps

    // retrieve certificate
    javax.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs = (javax.security.cert.X509Certificate[]) sslCertObject;
    javax.security.cert.X509Certificate x509Certificate = certs[0];

    // log the DN name of it
    String dn = x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().getName();
    log.info("Application is authenticate with certificate :  " + dn);

    // add certificate in to transport headers to send it to backend
    setCertificateAsHeader(axis2MessageContext, x509Certificate);

    return true;

} else {
    // if certificate is not available in the MessageContext,  it means that mutual SSL validation has been failed
    // in the transport level.

    // send 401 to client
    handleAuthFailure(messageContext);
}
```

Ref: http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/06/02/securing-apis-using-mutual-ssl-with-wso2-api-manager/

Note: As per the blog post, you still needs to configure mutual ssl for this.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that and calling from SOAPUI client and now after your comment, I ran using java client with client certificates but the sslCertObject  is always `null`

Comment: looks like the issue was with WSO2ESB as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608258/wso2esb-4-5-1-axi2-property-ssl-client-auth-cert-x509-is-always-null